# Siri and birthday events

Tags: iphone, ipad, calendar, siri

One of Apple's calendar features on every device is that it takes the birthdays from the contacts and show them as a separate birthday calendar. This is a nice feature, but has a huge drawback in my workflow:

Since I do a lot of driving I use Siri a lot to create calendar events. But when somebody of my contacts has birthday on the day I want to schedule a meeting (or whatsoever) the birthday event is recognized as a full-time event, what causes Siri to warn me, that I already have an appointment - what is obviously not true because it's "only" a birthday. Siri of course then tell me which appointments I have "at the same time" (which is a feature when you are connected via bluetooth), so at least I know, that this are only birthdays and I can schedule a meeting anyways, but this is also annoying, because if there are like 5 birthdays that day, it takes a pretty long while until Siri read all appointments to me.

So my question is: Is there any way to to get rid off the full-time status of the birthday calendar or even make Siri ignoring this birthday events (without deleting every birthday from any of my contacts)?

Comment: That's a great question. I just tried to edit a birthday event in the Mountain Lion Calendar to see if I could get rid of "all day" or change some other piece of the status so other events could coexist with it. I can't find a way to edit it on the Mac either. There was another question here about making other contact fields show up in Calendar which you might search for as it had some great answers that might overlap this question. I'll be interested in the answer(s) to this too. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make Siri stop seeing the Birthday calendar, even if you disable it in the Calendar app. You can always [write feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) or [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) (free developer account required).